# Avoid duplicates in inserting records to Pymongodb using custom field of the row

Tags: python, pymongo

How to avoid duplicates when adding records to mongodb based on the custom key (employeeid) which is added as a mandatory key for each row? If employee id exists then i shouldn't be able to insert/add any new records in pymongodb.

```
def add_employee():

star = mongo.db.employees   
_json = request.json   
_employeeid = _json['employeeid']   
_param2 = _json['Param2']   
_param3 = _json.get('Param3')   

if _employeeid and _param2 and _param3 request.method == 'POST':
 record_id = star.insert({'_employeeid': _param1, 'Param2': _param2})
return resp
```

Solution 1:

Below one didnt work and giving me an error stating upsert is not defined.

```
'''python
db.companies.updateOne(
{"company": "test"},
{ $setOnInsert: { "name": "nameVal2", ... } },
{ upsert: true }
)
'''
```

Any help would be highly appreciable ?

Comment: Try Finding it first in db using the id. If it is already in db then dont do anything, If its not inset it in the db

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can avoid duplicate record by creating unique index for the collection. In your case, you should execute this code `db.employees.createIndex( { employeeid: 1 }, { unique: true } )`

For more information about creating the unique index. Please refer this link: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/index-unique/

Comment: NameError: name 'unique' is not defined this is the error when i am getting now

Comment: This issue is resolved by updating db.employees.create_index( { employeeid: 1 }, { unique: True} ). thank you so much